Acumatica GI does not return any results in postman
Following this material: https://www.acumatica.com/blog/contract-based-apis-in-generic-inquiries/
I performed an exercise as detailed in the document and it works fine.
However, when I create my own GI, postman it does not return any results and I get an empty list.
Postman Result PO GI
Postman Result PO GI "Details" entity
The GI si basically two tables (POOrder and POLine) where you can see the detail that each PO contains.
Do you have any idea what I am missing?
Thank you very much for your support!
Best regards.
I'm expecting Postman send the results like this:
Expected result

On the Web Service Endpoints screen (SM207060), when you add a Generic Inquiry (GI) as an Entity to the endpoint, Acumatica auto-adds a "detail/result" entity named [GINAME]Details, not Results as seen on other system screen entities.
Example:
Added a simple GI called GenericInquiry with some fields from the Accounts table.
On adding the GenericInquiry GI to my Custom endpoint, a GenericInquiryDetails result entity was auto-added below GenericInquiry.
/entity/Custom/22.200.001/GenericInquiry?$expand=GenericInquiryDetails

The api call above returns the expected data from the GI.


Thanks! I create the "Result" entity in order to test, but with the original entity I have the same issue.
I already delete the "Result" entity. The result it's the same.
Image attached in the original post.
Regards.

I did replicate a similar issue after it auto-added the Result entity with all the fields. I removed a lot and left only the fields I needed and then it worked. You could try reducing the fields on the Results entity and work out which one/s are problematic, you may not need the one/s causing the incorrect response.

thanks! I will review it and let you know the result.

I did replicate a similar issue after it auto-added the Result entity with all the fields. I removed a lot and left only the fields I needed and then it worked. You could try reducing the fields on the Results entity and work out which one/s are problematic, you may not need the one/s causing the incorrect response. –
@Graeme LM
